# "Cannot detect post media type. Skip" InstaPy bot doesn't interact with posts

Tags: python, instapy

I am trying to write a code for instapy to like and comment on posts through tags. It shows up the tags page but does not interact with the posts.
My code:

```
session = InstaPy(username, password)                               
session.login()                                                                          
session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,max_followers=200)                          
session.set_do_follow(True,percentage=100)                                               
session.like_by_tags(["indiemusic", "heartbreakanniversary"], amount=5,interact=True)      
session.set_dont_like(["naked", "nsfw"])                                                 
session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=50)                                               
session.set_do_comment(True, percentage=50)                                              
session.set_comments(["Nice!", "S`weet!", "Beautiful :heart_eyes:"])                      
session.set_user_interact(amount=1,randomize=True,percentage=100)                        
session.end()
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a single word bug in the like_util.py file. It has been submitted as a bug and a merge request has been made. So at some point in the future, you can just reinstall InstaPy and it will get fixed.

In the meantime, if you still want to use the package, you have multiple options:

1. Find the like_util.py file on your system and change the last "span" to "div" on line 908. [See here](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/pull/6143/commits/2b3ab2d99e5a9f9ec8130a26823851203faa38db).
   You can find the possible directories in which instapy will be installed by running the following commands in a python shell.

   import sys;
   print(sys.path)

This prints a list of paths. On my system instapy is in a directory called site-packages/instapy in one of those paths.

2. Use virtual environment and install instapy in it and then modify the file like_util.py file there. Instructions for this can be found in the [additional information](https://instapy.org/additional-information/) tab of the [instapy.org documentation site](https://instapy.org).

Comment: I have installed the Instapy in Windows and I just looked the file with the normal windows search, I just edited and it has worked for me very well after that.

Comment: Please where can we find this file on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.
First, download the latest version of instapy or upgrade it.
https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy

Second, check all the recent changes in the file if it matches your local instapy from here.

https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/pull/6195/files/898f80175a5aaf8298dafdf82b5a70a34d443bf1?file-filters%5B%5D=#R97

And last not the list
Change span ----> div in these 2

1. "//a[@href='/p/" + post_href.split("/")[-2] + "/']/child::div"
2. - "/']/child::div[@class='u7YqG']/child::div"

make these two changes in the like_util.py in line 900 around on your local instapy packages.

After doing this it works perfectly on the date 29/08/2021

It was a tedious process but worth it.

Comment: Hey was wondering did u menaged to pass that selenium hide error??